# Laravel Helpers

Tags: laravel, caching, helper

Could someone please explain to me how a helper like `cache()` works. When I use

```
cache(['message' => 'This is a message'], 5);
```

how to map :

```
cache()->put('message', 'This is a message', 5);
```

and when I use :

```
cache('message');
```

how to map :

```
cache()->get('message');
```

Answer (score 1):

Helper functions such as `cache()`, `config()`, `session()` use `Service Locator` to initialize underlying class.

```
app('cache');
app('session');
app('config');
```

This [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L222) goes to the implementation of the `cache()` function. When you use;

```
cache(['message' => 'This is a message'], 5);
```

It is going to invoke this;

```
app('cache')->put(key($arguments[0]), reset($arguments[0]), $arguments[1] ?? null);
```

When you use;

```
cache('message');
```

it is going to invoke this;

```
return app('cache')->get(...$arguments);
```

which is same as `cache()->get('message')`